# RemoteViews only registering first PendingIntent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, remoteview

So I'm trying to figure out why my remoteviews objects in a notification seem to only be registering the first pendingintent I give it, when there's 3 buttons and 3 pendingintents being assigned...

My code for setting up the RemoteViews:

```
        RemoteViews remoteViewsBig = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_main_big);
        RemoteViews remoteViewsSmall = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.

        // Set up buttons
        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.ACTION_KEY, NotificationReceiver.ACTION_PREV);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        remoteViewsBig.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_prev, pendingIntent);
        remoteViewsSmall.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_prev, pendingIntent);

        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.ACTION_KEY, NotificationReceiver.ACTION_TOGGLE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        remoteViewsBig.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play, pendingIntent);
        remoteViewsSmall.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play, pendingIntent);

        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.ACTION_KEY, NotificationReceiver.ACTION_NEXT);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        remoteViewsBig.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_next, pendingIntent);
        remoteViewsSmall.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_next, pendingIntent);
```

The code for the NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String ACTION_KEY = "action";

public static final String ACTION_PREV = "prev";
public static final String ACTION_TOGGLE = "toggle";
public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "next";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = (String) intent.getExtras().get(ACTION_KEY);
    if (action == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide an Action to perform.");
    switch (action) {
        case ACTION_NEXT:
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new SkipEvent(SkipEvent.Direction.NEXT));
            break;
        case ACTION_PREV:
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new SkipEvent(SkipEvent.Direction.PREVIOUS));
            break;
        case ACTION_TOGGLE:
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new PlaybackToggleEvent());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide an Action to perform.");
    }
}
}
```

and the layout for the notifications for good measure:
notification_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_artwork" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="Song title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_artist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    tools:text="Artist name" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_black_36dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_48dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next_black_36dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

notification_main_big.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="128dp"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_artwork" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    tools:text="Song title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_artist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    tools:text="Artist name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_album"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_artist"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_album_art"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    tools:text="Album title" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/txt_album"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_album_art"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_black_36dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_48dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next_black_36dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenver I hit any of the 3 buttons, I'm getting ACTION_PREV in my NotificationReceiver instead of the appropriate action...

Comment: when calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` use different `requestCode`s

Comment: You need to use different request codes for each `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Well then... The docs don't descibe what that number means... Just "Private request code for the sender"

Comment: so use 0, 1, 2... etc

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, and it works like a charm. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the same request code in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method. They are zeros in your example, but have to be different for different intents. Just count them from zero up.

Answer (score 1):

The method `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` accepts the second parameter as the `requestCode` for the pending intent.

If you put `requestCode` as `0` for all the `pendingIntents`, it will keep replacing the previous `pendingIntent` with the same `requestCode` (0 in your case).

Give unique `requestCode` for each `pendingIntent`.

Answer (score 1):

your error here `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

 you must change requetcode in every intent  requestcode is second parameter

Answer (score 0):

u are use same request code for all PendingIntents.
use different request codes like 1,2,3.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, /*use different request codes*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```